# How to write openapi swagger file for ubuntu iptables rules auditing

Tags: iptables, api

I want to audit ubuntu iptable rules with openapi REST. So, I need swagger file. Can anyone guide me how to do this?
Actually I am using Azure Logic App and I want to use custome api connector for ubuntu iptable rules. I have to use openapi and I need openapi swagger file for it. If this post is not related with the forum, please suggest me where to ask.